# Facebook authentication bug in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm using the Facebook SDK in my app. Everything is good except one thing:
when user taps "Done" button in webView I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and app crashes. Any ideas why it happens? [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9ZoW.png)

Here the ViewController code:

```
@IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler:{ (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        } else {
            print("Smthng Wrong")
        }
    })
}
func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil) {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                print(result)
            }
        })
    } else {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point to which line this is starting? Probably, you are requesting a property on an object, but that object is nil. You need to check if/why that object is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you code is doing  -  as the facebook login is under the process of fetching data it requires the email to process it and as email is an optional type that's why xcode show a fatal error because it could not find the email when it requires. 
The solution is you just have to handle the error  like the code below
if the an error is nil show the alert or do something which you want

Hope it will help you.

Update you facebook Action with the  code below

```
    @IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler:{ (result, error) -> Void in
        if ((error) == nil) {
            //Show Alert Error Describing any message
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            print("result cancel")
        }
        else {
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    })
}
```